# Android Notification receive issue in latest devices

Tags: android, push-notification, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, onesignal

I am using appcelerator and one signal module for push notification, facing problem in receiving push notification in android oneplus 3 and above phones, also in Mi4i and many more phones with **Oreo OS**.

When app is in background or in foreground it receives notification, but when I remove app from my doc, then I am facing problem.

I am getting this error:-

```
broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.demo.notification (has extras) }
```

After looking over this, it shows that the service is been killed when you remove your app from doc list.

Help me out in this situation, this bug is very critical. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you got any solution. i'm facing same issue. if you found it please let me know.
i'm facing these issue in one plus device

Answer (score 1):

If you have upgraded your targetSDK version and compile sdk version to 26 or greater, then you must check the following link -- 
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-migration#rbr

2 things --

1. there are limitations on broadcastRecievers -- check - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts
2. also the notification will not be visible in status bar until they have a channel in it for devices greater than equal to Version.O (oreo) -- check - https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels